# vpn and strong authentication, how does the two work as a pair?

Tags: authentication, vpn

Dont know. maybe I was to unprecise....

I basically am asking if a SSL-VPN solution is solving both the encryption and the authentication, like that the user authenticates himself to the vpn-client with a certificate and by setup of the vpn-solution this will solve both the need for encryption(vpn with tls) and the strong authentication.

example: a user authenticates to the vpn-client on his client machine by use of 2fa, a smart card with his credentials, the vpn-client sends this data to the vpn server where the client is authenticated, a vpn-tunnel is created for this session. On the internal network the users credentials sent in the tunnel will be handled by authorization mechanisms against some kind of repository, an ad etc.

is this a feasible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Virtual Private Network on an end-user device (a PC for instance) is just that: a network which comes in addition to the ones you already have and which binds your client to a remote server/network though an encrypted tunnel.

It is set up after having received the authorization to do so in some way. This is usually bundled with the server/client solution you will use (and can be credentials, certificates, ...).

You should look at the VPN as an extension of the target network. You need to ensure you can connect to that network (the authentication part above) and then your traffic is similar to the one you would have in the LAN.

It is conceivable to have a VPN connection which is not authenticated. I fail to see a real usecase for that but this is to show that the VPN authentication is there to allow your client to connect to the target network (nor services).

Comment: Most kindly that you answered my question!